# Add an event to calendar

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I'm using the following code (from developer site) for inserting an event in device calendar-

```
long calID = 1;
long startMillis = 0;
long endMillis = 0;
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2015, 9, 6, 7, 00);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2015, 9, 6, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Test Title");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, tz.getID());
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

The code seems to work because I'm getting eventID of the inserted event.

After executing this, I'm not able to see the event in the calendar app. I tried with syncing the calendar from settings>accounts>google>calendar.

Is there something wrong in the code or any additional code that I've to add to see the events in the calendar?

Comment: Are you sure that `calID = 1` resolves to a calendar that really exists on your device? I guess you need to query an existing calendar ID that is really associated with your Google account before inserting an event: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Nobu Games, I solved the issue. The problem was calendarId = 1 was not associated with any of the calendar. I created a method to find out available calendarIds in the device using following code-

```
public MyCalendar [] getCalendar(Context c) {

String projection[] = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
Uri calendars;
calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

ContentResolver contentResolver = c.getContentResolver();
Cursor managedCursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null);

if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()){
    m_calendars = new MyCalendar[managedCursor.getCount()];
    String calName;
    String calID;
    int cont= 0;
    int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
    int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    do {
        calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
        calID = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
        m_calendars[cont] = new MyCalendar(calName, calID);
        cont++;
    } while(managedCursor.moveToNext());
    managedCursor.close();
}
return m_calendars;
}
```

And then I'm able to see the events in the calendar.